Stick lodging into front wheel - is it preventable?
I had a classic bike accident in a forest today. A short stick about 4cm thick got stuck into my front wheel, bent the mudguard into number 7, ripped three spokes from the rim and threw me over the handlebars. I'm fine and even managed to return home on wheels but it made me thinking if this kind of accident on a sandy forest path with sticks lying here and there is preventable at all?
Or is avoiding sticks the only way to do it? :-)
EDIT: A lot of good answers. Quick summary:

you can't just ride over sticks and expect nothing to happen
no mudguard, smaller mudguard, wider tyres, lower tire pressure, wider fork might reduce risk a bit
LOOK what you're riding over, like really, really do :-)


Get a Cannondale Lefty fork for a 50% risk reduction ;) Just joking.

I wonder if anyone makes a plastic spoke protector that would fill in the gaps between front wheel spokes.

@jpa cross-winds are a more common hazard that unluckily-flicked sticks.  It would have to be made of fairly open mesh

Sticks?!?!  Luxury!!  Last year I almost ran over a rattle snake that was pretending to be a stick!  It was sunning itself early morning right on the trail.  I missed it by 6 inches a d only realized it was a snake when I was 6" from it!

@jpa: done right, those shields might also act as wind fairings..

The mudguard isn't the issue here, it's just collateral damage. Anything caught between the spokes like that is going to hit a fundamental part of the bike and lock the wheel. Of course that's far worse on the front.
The best prevention really is avoidance. That could mean going round these big sticks, could mean bunny-hopping them (or at least lifting the front wheel, which is a bigger hazard if jammed) or if you can't avoid them, slowing down so much that you don't have enough momentum to go over the bars - this will also mean much less chance of damaging the bike.
Long sticks can break when you ride over them, and might be able to flick pieces in odd directions, however just clipping one as you try to go round it is probably the biggest risk of getting a non-rotten stick in your wheel. Totally rotten wood is more likely to crumble.
Of course after strong winds, especially when the leaves are still on the trees, there can be rather a lot of sticks to avoid; they can also be concealed rather well by fallen leaves and a last-minute dodge isn't always possible or wise.
A mountain bike's wider, lower pressure, tyres seem to offer some protection - I've ridden over many sticks and not always slowly on mine with soft tyres of 50-56mm, and never had a problem, but the time I've done something like this was on 37mm gravel tyres, pumped up to a compromise pressure between the road and gravel sections of my ride. MTB tyres will probably require a wider fork, this in itself may give some benefit.

Indeed, when this happened to me, it was after an episode of strong wind. No mudguards were involved.

I like the tyres size suggestion. I would add a wider MTB fork as well to the equation.

I thought I had a picture, but I don't.  Mine was a similar size (3-4cm thick, 15-20cm long) and the spokes embedded in the outer half-rotten bit when the stick hit both seatstays.  I left a skid mark of about 10m as I brought the bike gently to a halt with the front brake, not knowing what had happened until I inspected it

Lower pressure is the answer. Off-road cycling is about avoiding excess interaction with things around the trail.

@Therac yes, but it's not always feasible. Taking Saturday's ride as an example, I had 1% forest track, after the sort of weather that brings down branches. The other 220km were paved. Similar rides have more off-road, but often in little bits, and running gravel tyres as a (good) compromise there's a limit to how soft or wide you can go.

Stay home and watch MTB videos on the couch. Said mostly in jest, but the reality is sometimes through no fault of your own ..it happens.
Prevention might be possible with an insert in the wheel to turn it into a disk (or a disk wheel), meaning the stick could not go through the spokes, but the negatives probably outweigh the positives.
Removing mudguards and anything that could capture a stick, that is not absolutely needed could be worth considering. Do you really need mudguards in the sand? Perhaps changing to a style that is further away from the wheel - e.g. one mounted on the down tube - might be a good compromise.
Aside that avoiding sticks... Riding style might help - staying on the line everyone else rides, which will be clearer of sticks should help.

When I did the same at the back (on a mixed road/gravel ride when mudguards were definitely necessary) the mudguard was damaged but not part of the problem. The stick wedged between the spokes and the seatstays, hitting the mudguard stays on the way. Any decent front mudguards have connectors that pop out if anything gets caught in them anyway. So I bet much doubt the mudguard made things worse

@Chris Exactly, mudguard popped out (and bent), but the problem was thick piece of wood stuck between the wheel and the fork and between the spokes.

@mattnz I 'm running 32mm tires on 30+ years old steel road / audax bike so I was riding rather slow and pretty carefully - this was no race or downhill, just plain flat forest with some sandy patches and roots sticking out here and there, so nothing crazy. Also I'm used to passing even quite sandy roads on this bike but it's mostly paved roads for me so I was just wondering if there is something obvious I missed apart from going over loose piece of wood. Today I found a pic of an MTB with half of the spokes ripped from the rim in similar circumstances so I guess it could happen to anyone...

Also, 'avoid sticks' is absolutely satisfying answer if there are no other magic tricks :-).

@konrad it wasn't just you but the bike that was unlucky it was the front wheel. The back is more likely to skid and less likely to break stuff

TL;DR: smaller sticks break, larger sticks you shouldn't be hitting.
I've encountered the sub 1 cm non-rotten stick in the front spokes and thanks to:

the spokes being overbuilt by Specialized and
me not panicking

there have been no crashes. It's a distinct feeling when the bike tries to spit you out and the usual technique for that works: throwing your center of mass to the rear and down.
Large sticks - say your 4 cm - are just too large not to see. Here the question begins to sound like "I crash into big rocks, is there a technique to deal with big rocks?". The primary organ used in MTB are the the eyes with the legs a distinct second.
And a word on avoidance. In the search for freedom or adrenaline mountain bikers often venture into territories where medical help or even phone coverage are sketchy or not available. One must create a mental device which turns on on such trails and repeats to You:
- Yeah, this trail looks fascinating to blaze down; and we've won this with a whole day of sweat - but we're gonna ride it at reduced speed so that even if the worst happens we're fine - e.g. see that pile of leaves on the corner? There's an evil 4 cm stick concealed in it.

regarding your footnote, on off-road descents, where you're likely to be going too quickly to avoid a well-camouflaged hazard, you normally would have your weight further back and low.  Of course this can't prevent going over the bars, but it does increase the minimum speed needed

Good advice. In my defence, this was a thick but also very short stick probably hidden in the sand partially or I just ignored it - my memory is getting creative here. I have narrow tires so I'm usually super careful and quite slow in the forest - more like tiptoeing than racing, and I probably lost concentration for a bit to talk to a friend or sth like that.

@ChrisH thanks, I think I fixed it. The warning was a chilly reminder of my days of weighing as far back and wondering why steering doesn't work.

There are indeed wheel covers that will serve your purpose.  They are intended to be used by road racers to reduce drag, but they would certainly prevent flying debris from lodging in your spokes as well.  You can see some examples in a web search.  You can also buy rims that are a solid disk, usually carbon fiber.  And here's a budget alternative.



Great photo!  Welcome to the site.  It may be worth adding some of the downsides too, weight, rotational weight and crosswinds.

That photo is too strange to be a real rideable bike:  A frame inspired by a vintage beach cruiser with no pedals,  chain, brakes, or means to attach a sprocket - and the little wheels used to pull a folded Brompton along.  But with someone holding it up and trying to stay out of shot it may actually exist, just as a display piece

@ChrisH yeah if its outside, the reflections on the disk plates are wrong.   Its probably `shopped, but still illustrates the overall point fine.

@ChrisH It looks like an unfinished trick bike to me.

Those are Moon disc wheel covers by MoonEyes.  It's a circular brushed finish, which makes for interesting reflections.  It is a real photo.  Buy them here, currently US$92 each (not per pair): https://www.mooneyesusa.com/product-p/md2100bkf.htm

Also, another photo of the bike here: https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/mooneyes-moondisc-wheel-covers.96155/

Start by changing the front mudguard for a style that doesn't use stays?
There are plastic ones that are more self-supporting, and don't need a stay.  Downside they tend to be wider and wobblier.
This would give your front wheel another 1/8th of rotation to clear any obstructions, and then it hits the fork which is more robust.
The other way a traditional mudguard will hurt, is when the tail digs into the tyre's tread as the stays get shortened by being bent.
There is less urgency to change the rear mudguard.


Your bike has flawed mudguards.
You should buy mudguards that have a safety release mechanism on the stays. For example SKS Chromoplastics mudguards have automatic stay release (ASR).
With this safety release, if a stick gets caught in your spokes, the stay automatically releases from the fork and doesn't compress the mudguard into the fork crown.
Still, if the stick is big enough to break spokes, it still maybe can throw you over the handlebars. But at least for smaller sticks, the mudguard doesn't compress into the fork crown because of the safety release mechanism.
An alternative to safety release is a mudguard that's made from strong aluminum profile as opposed to plastic or thin metal. Those strong mudguards are used for example to carry panniers on the sides of the rear mudguard. In the front, the strength prevents the danger of the mudguard compressing after you encounter a stick. Hebie Alumee (formerly Wingee) is an example of such a strong mudguard.
You don't need to remove your mudguards to ride in the forest. A better mudguard is safer.

I have exactly SKS with safety release and the release worked fine but didn't help in the end. I was also able to reshape the mudguard and fit it back. The stick was thick enough to get stuck between the spokes and the fork so probably above some size of the wood it doesn't matter anymore, but it's still possible that it would fall to the side if it didn't catch the mudguard stays. I guess wider MTB fork has less tendency to 'catch' and wider tyre as Chris H writes raises less sticks in the air.

@konrad Interesting detail. Maybe riding without a mudguard then would prevent some of such accidents. After all, because the stick was only 4cm log, one would not expect it to stay between the spokes at all unless held in place there (in this case, by the mudguard). -- As an aside, glad you are OK.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica 4cm thick, not 4cm long, in the question

I guess the safety release would have prevented flying over the bars, if the stick would have been smaller. Without the safety release, even a small stick can jam the mudguard into the fork crown, causing an over-the-bars accident.

@ChrisH Oh. A tree! ;-)
